# Retrieve a bitcoin

Tags: blockchain

On June 8th I sent a bitcoin from coinbase. I have the address and the private key. When I look it up on blockchain info it exists, but how do I retrieve it and either send it back to coinbase or put it on a trezor?

Comment: I would be certain before moving it again. Also coinbase does not facilitate sending into coinbase, only receiving into coinbase, so you need a wallet, or some application which can publish bitcoin transactions. However the address for your coinbase wallet you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Import the private key into the wallet software of your choice. That software will scan the blockchain for the transactions related to that private key. Then make a transaction with the software to send the Bitcoin elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but how do I import the private key? On Blockchain info, I can't find the facility to do this.

Comment: I don't use blockchain.info so I can't help you there. If your wallet does not support online private let's, you can switch to using a different one. I personally recommend electrum.

Comment: @Mark. many people believe that if you use a third party to store your bitcoins, you are very vulnerable to hacking of the third-party service, to theft by insiders at that service or to the financial collapse of that service. Bitcoin was created with the objective of not having to rely on third party services. You can install a [desktop wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) and import your private key into it and then control your bitcoins regardless of what happens to the blockchain.info company. Backup your wallet and your private key and practise wallet-recovery.